# Selenium Wait for element works only when debug selected test

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I have webpage built using ajax.
In code there is a method:

```
public static void ProceedButtonClick()
{
    Driver.WaitForAndIsEnabledFind(ProceedButtonElementBy).Click();
    Driver.WaitFor(LoadedPageFinishedIdentifierBy);
}
```

As you can see I only click and later wait for next window to show.
When I run this code by 'run selected test' test freezes at wait and gets time outed. But the window is visible on the page. I can see it in a browser.
If I run this code by 'debug selected test' everything works. I don't even need to put breakpoints. Debug mode is enough. Selectors are ok. I double checked them.
Here is my WaitFor method:

```
public static void ProceedButtonClick()
{
    Driver.WaitForAndIsEnabledFind(ProceedButtonElementBy).Click();
    Driver.WaitFor(LoadedPageFinishedIdentifierBy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

always try to use below method for explicit wait, which will keep check the element for every 3 sec and click.

Method:

```
  public static void waitForElementToBeVisible(final WebDriver driver,
        final By locator) throws RuntimeException {
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
    try {
        wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                // driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
                if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                    return element;
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception while waiting for " + locator
                + ". Exception:" + e + " on " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code before finding the elements:

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```